# Validação sem o "ModelState.isValid"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Create(string dados)
    {
        var clienteViewModel = DeserializeJson<ClienteViewModel>(dados);
        if (ModelState.IsValid) { } // Não têm como validar.
        ...
    }
```

Recebo o json e converto para o objeto ClienteViewModel, mas dessa forma não é possível eu validar com o "ModelState.isValid" porque ele valida o modelo que está no parâmetro.

Não quero ter que enviar o formulário normalmente para a Action e no seu parâmetro colocar o ClienteViewModel ao invés do "string dados (json)" pois isso faz com que a página toda seja carregada, e não quero isso.

Existe alguma forma de validar a ViewModel dessa maneira?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você não consegue fazer dessa maneira abaixo:
se os atributos estiverem exatamente com mesmo nome da viewmodel ele consegue receber todos os parâmetros e não precisa deserializar.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Create(ClienteViewModel model)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid) { }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Ah sim, valeu. Acabei de testar dessa forma e deu certo!

Comment: Complementando: o nome desse recurso é *binding* (não tem um nome bom para o português). A classe que implementa isto é [`DefaultModelBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx). [Sua implementação está aqui](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs).

Answer (score 6):

O ideal é validar pelo `ModelState`, como mostrado na resposta do [@EduardoSampaio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167893/20615). Porém, você consegue sim validar de outra forma.

Para fazer a validação, você necessita utilizar a [classe ValidationContext.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Um exemplo seria este:

```
var clienteViewModel = DeserializeJson<ClienteViewModel>(dados);
List<ValidationResult> restuls = new List<ValidationResult>();
ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(clienteViewModel, null, null);


bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(clienteViewModel, context, restuls, true);

if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var validationResult in restuls)
    {
        var pause = true;
    }
}
```

Outra opção seria você utilizar o[DataAnnotations Validator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsValidator/).

Basta instalar o pacote com o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package DataAnnotationsValidator

E para utilizar, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
var clienteViewModel = DeserializeJson<ClienteViewModel>(dados);
var validator = new DataAnnotationsValidator.DataAnnotationsValidator();
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = validator.TryValidateObjectRecursive(clienteViewModel , validationResults);
```

O código original do pacote você pode ver [nesta resposta o autor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090614/4843158). Mas, em resumo, ele apenas utiliza o `ValidationContext` da "mesma forma".

Caso queira saber mais, pode olhar [este artigo](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) e [esta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33286428/4843158)